# Is it mandatory to use corporate colors (i.e company color logo) on all company products (digital)

Tags: color, business

I want to know if there are any hard and fast rules for using corporate colors in company products especially for dashboards and layout colors.Can I use any other color apart from the company colors.

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely to attract a lot of down votes and may even get closed for being too broad, but before that happens, I'll give you a quick answer: It depends.

The rules for that colours can be used will be set by the corporate style guide of the company in question. Some companies will insist on a very limited corporate palette for all design work, must will have primary brand colours that are backed up by a secondary (and even tertiary) palette for use in (usuallY) well defined circumstances and many will have different palettes, colour standards and rules for different media (i.e. print, digital, signage).

You will need to find out what the rules are for your customer and then see whether you are allow to break them or not.

Answer (score 0):

If company have a book of graphic standards...then YES, you have to follow the prescribed rules. This is called branding.

If company insists on some color palete..then YES again, but you can try to combine their color with some other color. This is called - satisfy the client.

If you choose the color scheme, then you should use color from their logo..even some shades. This is called - you are designer.

I hope I helped